# Metal array indexing works using literals but crashes using a variable

Tags: ios, arrays, metal

I have an array in a compute kernel that stores a series of values (only around 10 for now). I assign the values to the array as below:

```
int count = uniforms;
int i = 0;
float pointsx[count];
float pointsy[count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
  pointsx[i] = simplex3D(i*2,1,1);
  pointsy[i] = simplex3D(1,i*2,1);
}
```

I then go on to iterate over these points using a similar for loop.
This crashes at runtime reporting a compiler error when I try and access the array at any index, however if I were to replace the `i` with an integer literal it works.

I feel I'm missing something very obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Even in cases where the error may seem obvious, it's never acceptable for the compiler to return an "internal compiler error" rather than a more useful diagnostic. This is worth filing a bug report for.

Comment: For a temporary fix I just handed a buffer of the correct size into the compute kernel to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable-length arrays are not supported in Metal. Since there is a small upper bound on the number of entries in the array, you can declare an array of that size. Using a buffer is more flexible, but requires you to read from device memory.

Comment: can i also declare a new constant int and init the array from that?

Comment: If you're talking about initializing the array's elements all to a certain constant integer, I don't see why not. If you're talking about specifying the array's length with a constant integer, I believe it would need to be declared as `constexpr`.